# How can I diagnose root login failure to Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When attempting to connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance via various MySQL clients, the root login is now failing with the error:

$ mysql --host=173.194.x.x --user=root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'98.225.x.x' (using password: YES)

I was previously able to login and perform various tasks (create a local user, add tables and store procedures, etc.).

I can still login as the local user I created.

So, I have:

- Confirmed the instance "IP Address"
- Confirmed the "Authorized Networks"
- Set and reset the "Root Password" multiple times
- "Reset SSL Configuration"
- Cleared the checkbox for "Only allow SSL connections"
- "Restarted" the instance multiple times

Any suggestions on diagnosing root login failure?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With the user that can connect to the DB, can you check: `SELECT user,host,ssl_type FROM mysql.user;` and see if `root@%` has `ssl_type` set to `X509`? if it does, delete the user from that table and reset the password from the UI.

Comment: Thanks, Juan, but that user does not permission to query "users":

ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'roms'@'98.225.x.x' for table 'user'

Are you thinking I should reenable SSL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a manifestation of a bug. Please follow the status of the bug [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=81).

As a workaround please try the following steps:

1. Add SSL to the instance (if one is not in place)
2. Connect using user = root with the SSL
3. Remove the user root@%
4. Uncheck (if checked) the "Only allow SSL connections"
5. Set the root password again
6. Now try and connect with user = root and the password that was set.

Comment: I was able to connect as root using SSL, but was not able to reset the root password w/o SSL.  root still requires SSL.